# !isset vs == null PHP, Singleton Class

Tags: php, null, singleton, isset

the issue I'm wondering about may be more of a matter of style or what have you. I have a singleton class in PHP. When I check to see if the object has already been created, I simply do:

```
if(self::$instance == null)
  self::$instance = new self();
```

However, I've seen some implementations of the singleton pattern in PHP do !isset:

```
if(!isset(self::$instance))
  self::$instance = new self();
```

According to my understanding, there is no functional difference between these two statements. Is one way better than the other? Is one way more professional than the other?

EDIT:

Here is the code for the whole pattern inside my singleton class:

```
private static $instance = null;

private function __construct() {    }

public static function getInstance() {
    if(self::$instance == null) {
        self::$instance = new self();
    }
        return $instance;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Provided that you have `instance` defined as a protected/private static variable, they are functionally the same and it does not really matter which one you use.

Personally, I view `isset` as more in the spirit of PHP and the == NULL as closer to Java, but that is a style issue.

Comment: Personally I prefer the `null` check, but it seems to me sloppy to use `==` instead of `===` -- even though again, there will be no functional difference.

Comment: @Jon In this case there isn't a difference, but I agree `== null` rubs me very much the wrong way. That's probably because the loose equality check is no different from the `!self::$instance`. Of course, `!self::$instance` is another, equally valid approach.

Answer (score 0):

the first one is bad; if $instance is not exist it will be error!

Comment: Well in this case, $instance is defined as null in previous code. Let me show you what I have:

private static $instance = null;
 
 private function __construct() { }
 
 public static function getInstance() {
  if(self::$instance == null) {
   self::$instance = new self();
  }
  return $instance;
 }


So do you still recommend !isset ?

Comment: OK, why you didn't say that?

Answer (score 0):

Use `isset()` when you're not sure if the variable is there or not. In your case the variable is there always. Also you could write it like this:

```
if(is_null(self::$instance))
  self::$instance = new self();
```

I would write like this:

```
public static function getInstance() {
    return is_null(self::$instance) ? new self() : self::$instance;
}
```